# swibable buttons on an arc

Tags: ios, animation, uibutton, swipe

I want to arrange 5 buttons in a curve. Everytime middle button is the clickable. I should be able to swipe buttons along the arc. When I swipe, the next button should come to the middle and should be bigger than other buttons and it should be enable.

Is there any github example or sample code this kind of button arrangements? Please help me.

Thank you

Comment: do you mean like the scaling effect in the dock of mac? http://safalra.com/web-design/javascript/mac-style-dock/

Comment: yes but this scaling should happen when swipe the button and need to arrange those in an arc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey You can use iCarosel for what you wanted to do....

There are many examples and source code available.

One of them link which is github example code as well as source code is avaliable on this link [Click Here.](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel)

Comment: Hello thanks for answering. But this is not what I needed. I need something like this https://github.com/johnscode/JCArcButtonWheelView . But here I want to customize my circle. But when I change the radius and center point values it gives NaM to the theta1 and theta2 so I dunno how to customize this exactly.